# latex code for kernel in category theory

Tags: tikz-cd

[image]

I need latex code for this picture. Could you please help me provide one using the package tikz-cd? I don't know latex properly.

Also, how can I reverse arrows in the diagram later?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Have you tried anything?  If so, could you add it to your question as a small compilable document and we can help you with the pieces that don't work as you want. The `tikz-cd` manual is very good and there are plenty of examples similar to this in it that could form a starting point.

Comment: Hi Alan, I am learning tex for the first time. All I have learnt till now is \usepackage{tikz-cd}. \begin{tikz-cd} and \end{tikz-cd} for drawing figures.

Comment: @GeetThakur, the [package documentation for tikz-cd is here](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd). It's quite good with many examples. The figure at the top of page 3 has many of the same attributes as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of diagram is basically what `tikz-cd` was designed to do.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1cm, column sep=.75cm]
X\arrow[rr, "f"] & & Y\\
& K\arrow[ul, "k"']\arrow[ur, "0"']\\
& L\arrow[uul, bend left, "l"]\arrow[u,dashed,"\exists!g"]\arrow[uur, bend right, "0"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

By default, arrow labels are on the "left" side of the arrow (if you were walking along the arrow from its source toward its destination), so if you want to put a label on the opposite side of its arrow you can add (or remove) the additional `'` after the double quotes for the corresponding label. You can change `row sep` and `column sep` to get the spacing however you like.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sandy G. That was helpful. However, I am unable to reverse the arrows by removing the additional '. Do I need to remove all ' at once and then try to recompile it?

Comment: For example, if you want the `l` to be on the other side of its arrow, change `"l"` to `"l"'`. If you want to switch the `0` map from `L` to `Y`, remove the extra single quote after `"0"`.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. But my question about reversing arrows meant that I want the same labels but with direction of arrows changed. For example, how can I change f: X --> Y to f:Y-->X by keeping the labels at the same position?

Comment: @GeetThakur, in that case you may want to move the `\arrow` command after the `Y` and make its direction `ll` instead of `rr` (arrow points 2 cells to the left). Also, since the arrow will point from right to left, you'll want to switch the position of the `f` label using `"f"'`. So the first row of the diagram would be `X & & Y\arrow[ll, "f"']`. Alternatively, you can just change the direction of the arrow by making the first row `X\arrow[<-,rr, "f"] & & Y`.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks! So, can I do the same for the bent and other arrows as well?

Comment: Yes. Just try it.